# How to combine two regex pattern in perl?

Tags: perl

I want to combine two regex pattern to split string and get a table of integers.

this the example :

```
$string= "1..1188,1189..14,14..15";
$first_pattern = /\../;
$second_pattern = /\,/;
```

i want to get tab like that:

```
[1,1188,1189,14,14,15]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `|` to connect alternatives. Also, use `qr//` to create regex objects, using plain `/.../` matches against `$_` and assigns the result to `$first_pattern` and `$second_pattern`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $string = '1..1188,1189..14,14..15';
my $first_pattern = qr/\.\./;
my $second_pattern = qr/,/;

my @integers = split /$first_pattern|$second_pattern/, $string;
say for @integers;
```

You probably need `\.\.` to match two dots, as `\..` matches a dot followed by anything but a newline. Also, there's no need to backslash a comma.